# I am using a YAML file to parse object values to DataFilter object

Tags: yaml

My DataFilter class looks like this-

```
public class DataFilter {
  private String widgetName;
  ...
  private Map<FormInfo, WidgetInfo> objectMapping;
}
```

And objects in **objectMapping** are something like this-

```
public class FormInfo {
    private String name;
    private String path;
}

public class WidgetInfo {
    private String value;
    private String message;
}
```

Now,in my YAML file I want to provide object values. How do I define **objectMapping** in YAML file?

If the map has key and value as string type then I can give it as

```
testMapping:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Since **objectMapping** map has object as key and value, how do I define it in YAML? Can someone help me out in this please..

Answer (score 0):

YAML mappings can have complex keys:

```
objectMapping:
  ? name: spam
    path: egg
  : value: sausage
    message: spam
```

`?` starts a complex key, `:` on the same level starts the respective value.

It's also possible to have inline keys if you use flow style:

```
objectMapping:
  {name: spam, path: egg}:
    value: sausage
    message: spam
```

The two YAML snippets are equivalent. Note that an inline key must not contain a line break.